# Easy Regex capture

Tags: c#, regex, capture

New to using C# Regex, I am trying to capture two comma separated integers from a string into two variables.

Example: `13,567`

I tried variations on

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d+),(\d+)");
var matches = regex.Matches("12,345");

foreach (var itemMatch in matches)
    Debug.Print(itemMatch.Value);
```

This just captures 1 variable, which is the entire string. I did workaround this by changing the capture pattern to `"(\d+)"`, but that then ignores the middle comma entirely and I would get a match if there were any text between the integers.
How do I get it to extract both integers and ensure it also sees a comma between.

Comment: why don't you use `split`?

Comment: In your match you need to look at `Groups`

Comment: I guess I could, but as I hadn't used regex before I thought this was a trivially easy example to learn a bit about it. I found it frustrating awkward, and have yet to solve it. So would appreciate  a solution using regex. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

## Can do this with String.Split

Why not just use a split and parse?

```
var results = "123,456".Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
var left = results[0];
var right = results[1];
```

Alternatively, you can use a loop and use `int.TryParse` to handle failures but for what you're looking for this should cover it

## If you're really committed to a Regex

You can do this with a Regex too, just need to use groups of the match

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(\d+)\,(\d+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var r1 = r.Match("123,456");
    
//first is total match
Console.WriteLine(r1.Groups[0].Value);
    
//Then first and second groups
    
var left = int.Parse(r1.Groups[1].Value);
var right = int.Parse(r1.Groups[2].Value);
    
Console.WriteLine("Left "+ left);
Console.WriteLine("Right "+right);
```

Made a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7h2wUL) you can test the solution in as well

Comment: The question is not about how to split a string, but about how to access capture groups. Everyone knows how to split a string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew question was about a Regex but the solution was obtainable with a split, added how to accomplish what OP was looking for wth a Regex as well

Answer (score 0):

With Regex, you can use this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+(?=,)|(?<=,)\d+");
var matches = regex.Matches("12,345");

foreach (Match itemMatch in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(itemMatch.Value);
```

prints:

```
12
345
```

Actually this is doing a look-ahead and look-behind a `,` :

```
\d+(?=,)     <---- // Match numbers followed by a ,
|            <---- // OR
(?<=,)\d+    <---- // Match numbers preceeded by a ,
```

Comment: The point is not how to write a "better" regex, but how to access captured values.

Comment: Eugh, smelling salts required pleased ! For what I thought was a simple problem, that is a horrific looking regex template for a newb to understand.

Comment: @geoffw123 don't think it is helpful to make comments like that personally, could simply say that it looks over complicated...that being said do agree that this looks like a sub-optimal way to handle the problem

Comment: @geoffw123 I added a description.

Comment: Tech topics are a bit dry to read and regex questions are particularly bad I think, so a bit of polite levity and humour is no bad thing. I was impressed by the posters Regex "Ninja" ness, but the template still gave me a headache.  Thanks for the replies guys, the word "group" was enough for me to solve it myself. I was a bit surprised by the fact that group index[0] returns the entire string. That was non intuitive, wonder why it does that ?

Comment: P.S thanks for the extra explanation of that template. My headache is wearing off a bit :)